# ActiveAdmin change password inside app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I went off the [Devise Page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password)  so that users can change their password inside ActiveAdmin. The method 3 doesn't work as is, so I had to modify it a bit for ActiveAdmin

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'UserPassword' do

  def user_params
    params.required(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  page_action :update_password, method: :post do
    @user = AdminUser.find(current_admin_user.id)
    if @user.update(params.required(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation))
      # Sign in the user by passing validation in case their password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to admin_root_path, notice: "Your password was changed"
    else
      redirect_to admin_userpassword_path, alert: "Your password couldn't be changed"

    end
  end

  content do
    render partial: 'edit', locals: {user: current_admin_user}
  end
end
```

I had to change `if @user.update(params.required(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation))` because `if (@user.update(user_params))` would throw an error saying `undefined local variable or method user_params`

is the code I have listed above the correct approach to being able to let users change their passwords inside the ActiveAdmin layout?

Answer (score 0):

I would register the User model as a **resource** in ActiveAdmin. Then you can use the form block to create a form, where the use can change the password.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  ...
  form do |f|
    inputs 'Details' do
      input :password
      input :password_confirmation
    end
    actions
  end
  ...
end
```